# Security Alert in Android App

Tags: android, android-security, trustmanager

For one of my App, I got the security alert in android developer console. I do not use http request. I am not sure about the AD network like Admob and Facebook which uses this.

Any specific code / gradle setup is needed for this ?

How to solve this issue and come out of security alert ?

[image]

Comment: What is the link to the "Google Help Center article"?

Comment: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016

Comment: "To properly handle SSL certificate validation, change your code in the checkServerTrusted method of your custom X509TrustManager interface to raise either CertificateException or IllegalArgumentException whenever the certificate presented by the server does not meet your expectations." Tried that?

Comment: It could be because of the ads

Comment: But I use the Facebook and Admob.. Only admob mediates to facebook. Does it mean i have to remove these ?

Comment: Will there be a logcat for this issue. ? How it will be ?    if so I can remove the libraries and test to find which one is causing this issue

Comment: decompile your apk and search there where that class is referred

Comment: Which class I need to look for ?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35465916/624109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X509TrustManager` is an interface which is used to trust all the certificates.
If this interface being used anywhere in your app (though you're not using it directly there might be chances that third-party lib using it).So make sure you don't use it which is vulnerable for man-in-the-middle attack.

> How to solve this issue and come out of security alert?

Search for `X509TrustManager` and remove it's corresponding usage and imports.

and ugrade the version code of your app upload it to playstore.

Refer : [X509TrustManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html)  and [Google help center](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016)