# Security alert for insecure TrustManager

Tags: android-security, trustmanager

In one of my apps I recently got the following alert from Google Play saying:

> Your app is using an unsafe implementation of the X509TrustManager interface with an Apache HTTP client, resulting in a security vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.

Can someone provide more details on what should be updated?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465916/google-play-security-alert-for-insecure-trustmanager).