# Getting security issue on Google Developer Console

Tags: android-security, trustmanager

> **Your app is using an unsafe implementation of the X509TrustManager interface with an Apache HTTP client**, resulting in a security
>   vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article for details,
>   including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.

This message is shown in my app on Developer Console.
 I have not implemented `X509TrustManager`. So, it must be in one of the libraries used in app.

**How can I figure out which library is resulting in this issue?**

Comment: I think that will be pointed out in the mail itself. Check the last part of that mail sent by Google

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35465916/624109