# How to successfully upload my app to the play store without WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError

Tags: android, google-play, android-webview, android-security, sslerrorhandler

Recently I updated my app and tried to upload the Google Play Store again.
But my app rejected several times due to this warning

> Your application uses an old version ( not secure one ) of Lib 
>   WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError .
>        Check this article https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7071387  to know more about it
>        Vulnerable Classes com.ironsource.mobilcore.Utils$b

but unfortunately I cannot find `WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError` on my app.
actually what I did on my new version is just update Google AdMob Ads SDK and implement some Restful api using ASynchttpclient.

Is there any way to avoid this warning and upload my new updated app?

Comment: search for method onReceivedSslError not webviewclient.onReceivedSslError http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050741/webview-avoid-security-alert-from-google-play-upon-implementation-of-onreceiveds ( also include any library that you may have used in your app )

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to find the function onRecievedSslError, but I cannot find it except for come.ironsource.mobilecore. how can I fix it?

Comment: see solution provided in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465916/google-play-security-alert-for-insecure-trustmanager/35531561

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the alert, the issue is with the class `com.ironsource.mobilcore.Utils$b`. You need to figure out which SDK that class comes from and update it.